# Getting an object's parent type on runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna, monogame

I've been struggling with a problem for a little while now, and I'm not sure if it has an actual solution.

I've been trying to write a function that iterates through a list of a certain object type and returns only the objects that are (or inherit from) another type.

```
    public List<Entity> getEntities(Type t)
    {
        List<Entity> returnList = new List<Entity>();

        foreach (Entity e in entityList)
        {
            if (e is t)
            {
                returnList.Add(e);
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

This is the code I've been working with. The problem is that **is** doesn't work with variables, and any other solution that I've found does not check inheritance, which leads me to believe that this can't be done on runtime.

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting, or do I need to find an altogether different solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Type.IsAssignableFrom method to check inheritance.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx